# how to disable swiping of pages in a view in page based application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

In my App i am using  a page based application where swiping of page will happen in two ways

1.By swiping of fingers

2.By tapping

i have disabled tapping of pages using code.

Now what my requirement is i have a button where click on button i add a view top of it.In this view when i swipe by fingers the swiping of pages still happens which should not.so how to disable the swiping of pages when i add a view. Below is the code where i had a view.In this view i want to disable swiping action

```
-(IBAction)goTopopUp:(id)sender{
    myView.hidden = NO;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5];
    [self.pageViewController.view addSubview:myView];
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];
}
```

NOTE: Its a page based application

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)goTopopUp:(id)sender{
    myView.hidden = NO;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5];
    [self.pageViewController.view addSubview:myView];
    self.pageViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];
}
```

Then, when hiding view switch it to YES

Comment: still it happens swiping of page...i am using above code its not working

Comment: strange..you are doing something wrong..you should set 'userInteractionEnabled = NO' to rootController's view

Comment: try self.view (because I don't know what is self and what is pageViewController)

Comment: if i try self.view it wont interact with total which i am adding..so where i am going wrong.???i am draggin view in rootviewcontroller

Comment: how do you hide the image which you add?

Comment: i am not going to hide image i am going to hide complete view like this myView.hidden = YES;when i press button myview slides down where i have tabelview and other stuff..but there this swiping action still works.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `UIPageViewController`'s `dataSource` methods. Check if your view is visible, and if yes, `return nil;` in `– pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and
`– pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:`. Hope this helps :).